# "encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)" when I call the following django api code to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

```
import os

from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, baseblobservice
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_to_blob(request):
    try:
        container_name = 'xyzxyzxyz'
        connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=dapblobstorage;AccountKey=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgh==;"
        local_file_path = "D:\Work\\uploadToBLOB API\\test\\a4.csv"
        upload_location = "kuldeep/api"

        block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(connection_string)

        if os.path.exists(local_file_path):
            block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name=container_name
                                                    , blob_name=(upload_location.strip('/') + '/' + os.path.basename(local_file_path))
                                                    , file_path=local_file_path)

        return JsonResponse({'message': f'{os.path.basename(local_file_path)} uploaded successfully!'}, status=200, safe=False)
    except Exception as err:
        loggers.error(err, exc_info=True)
        return JsonResponse({'message': f'File upload failed with error - {err}'}, status=500, safe=False)
```

Response : {"message": "File upload failed with error - encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label too long)"}

Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue was caused by your incorrect code `block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(connection_string)`.

According to the constructor function `BlockBlobService` in the source code of [`azure-storage-python/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py), as the figure below,

[image]

if you want to use the connection string of Azure Storage to create a `BlockBlobService` object, you should pass the value of your `connection_string` variable to its parameter `connection_string` as the code below.

```
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(connection_string=connection_string)
```

If not, the value of your `connection_string` variable will be as the `account_name` parameter's value and cause the issue https://bugs.python.org/issue32958 which be used into the url of Azure Storage while opening the socket.

Meanwhile, please add a backslash to `D:\` of `local_file_path` to make it correct and avoid to be used as escape charater for `W` of `Work`, or just use slash `/` instead of double-backslash `\\` in the path, `D:/Work/uploadToBLOB API/test/a4.csv` is as same as `D:\\Work\\uploadToBLOB API\\test\\a4.csv` on Windows.